# Drupal 7: LDAP Authentication failing for old users

Tags: drupal-7, ldap

I have some users that have had no problems at all in the past. All of a sudden they can't log in anymore. Nothing has changed in the OUs in Active Directory. All other users can log in, no problem. It's just these two. The only thing I can see is in the 'field_data_ldap_user_current_dn' table their 'ldap_user_current_dn_value' got set to null. I manually set this in the db back to the correct dn, but this didn't help. How can I get these users their access back?

### Edit:

Whenever cron gets run these two users get their DNs nullified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is another solution, but I had to delete the users account and assign their content to anonymous. Then they logged in using LDAP credentials and the account was created successfully. Then I just had to assign their content back to them.